# How to find all files in subdirectories that match pattern and replace pattern

Tags: linux, bash

I am attempting to move some video files of mine into new subdirectories while also renaming them on my Unraid system. The files all follow a similar naming convention:

```
featurette name-featurette.mkv
```

I would like to move these files from their current directory to a subdirectory and rename them like this:

```
featurettes/featurette name.mkv
```

I am able to create the directories and relocate the files using find and execdir:

```
find . -type f -name *-featurette.mkv -maxdepth 2 -execdir mkdir ./featurettes/ \;
find . -type f -name *-featurette.mkv -maxdepth 2 -execdir mv {} ./featurettes/ \;
```

I am struggling with the renaming piece. I've tried the rename command but am unable to get it to work within the featurettes directory, let alone from two directories above, which is where I'd like to execute the command. I've tried the following command within the featurettes directory:

```
rename \-featurette.mkv .mkv *
```

However I get the error:

```
invalid option -- 'f'
```

I thought by escaping the dash I could avoid that issue, but it doesn't appear to work. Any advice on how to remove this pattern from all files within subdirectories matching it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Use quotes and so rename "-featurette.mkv" ".mkv" *

Comment: also, you don' t have to call `mkdir`mutiple times like you do, for all the files from the find command. Just once, `mkdir -p your/name` and then move and rename.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man rename` you see this command gets options and 3 positional parameters:

> SYNOPSIS
> rename [options] expression replacement file...

So in your case the first parameter is being interpreted as an option. You may use this syntax:

```
rename -- '-featurette' '' *-featurette.mkv
```

to rename the files. `--` indicates that any options are over and what follows are only positional parameters.

---

Totally, to copy the files with one `mv` process and rename them:

```sh
mkdir -p target/dir
find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -name "*-featurette.mkv" -exec mv -t target/dir {} +
cd target/dir && rename -- '-featurette' '' *-featurette.mkv
```

---

If you want to rename many files located into different subdirectories, you can use this syntax:

```sh
find . -name "*-featurette.mkv" -print0 | xargs -r0 rename -- '-featurette' ''
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
find . \
  -maxdepth 2 \
  -type f \
  -name '*-featurette.mkv' \
  -execdir sh -c '
echo mkdir -p ./featurettes/
echo mv -- "$@" ./featurettes/
' _ {} \+
```

Issue with your implementations I fixed or improved:

- `-maxdepth 2` must precede `-type f`
- `-name '*-featurette.mkv'` must have the pattern quoted to prevent the shell to expand globb it.
- `-execdir` is best used with an inline shell, so it can also process multiple arguments from the same directory

Also keep in mind that while running a command with `-execdir`, `find` will `cd` to that directory. It means that `mv -- "$@" ./featurettes/'` will move files into the `./featurettes/'` directory **relative** to were `-execdir` has just `cd`.

Version which also rename files while moving:

*( has no `echo` dry-run protection, so use **only** if you are sure it does what you want )*

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

find . \
  -maxdepth 2 \
  -depth \
  -name '*-featurette.mkv' \
  -type f \
  -execdir sh -c '
mkdir -p featurettes
for arg
do
  basename=${arg##*/}
  mv -- "$basename" "./featurettes/${basename%-featurette.mkv}.mkv"
done
' _ {} +
```

Comment: hmm, this didn't seem to work., it just seemed to echo the mkdir command and the mv command for each of the featurette files.

Comment: @kwatz Quite obviously I placed the `echo` to protect you of potential damages from enthusiast copy-pasting. Your comment just confirm they are there for very good reasons.

Comment: Sorry, it's not quite obvious to those without much experience in bash.

Comment: This works for moving the files more elegantly than my original solution, but doesn't address the issue of removing the -featurette part of the filenames

Comment: @kwatz, This is it exactly. Just a courtesy, because the code could have unintended side-effects. It is also a reminder to not run code you find here, unless you understand what it does. Moderation would probably remove intentionally malign code, but honest human errors and not fully knowing the environment or how it will be used, means you should always understand, the code before using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bash's shell parameter expansion feature to get the part of the file name, for example:

```sh
$> filename=name-featurette.mkv
$> echo ${filename%-*} #To print first part before '-'
name
$> echo ${filename##*.} #To get the extension
mkv
$> echo ${filename#*-} #To print the part after '-' with extension
featurette.mkv
```

With this and slightly modifying your find command, you should be able to move+rename your files:

```sh
find . -type f -name '*-featurette.mkv' -maxdepth 2 -execdir sh -c 'f="{}"; mv -- "$f" ./featurettes/"${f%-*}.mkv"' \;
```

In fact you should be able to combine both the find command into one to create_dir, move and rename file.

```sh
find . -type f -name '*-featurette.mkv' -maxdepth 2 -execdir sh -c 'f="{}"; mkdir ./featurettes; mv -- "$f" ./featurettes/"${f%-*}.mkv"' \;
```

Comment: `mkdir -p` as it will throw warnings after the first creation